# Why Linux shell command is right in comand line, but it's error in shell file?

Tags: linux, shell

"paste -d'|' <(echo 22)

the code is righ in command line , but I wrote it to a shell file , it's error.

[image]

this result :

[image]

How to resolve this!
Thinks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Please don't use screen shots of code/data that can be copy/pasted. Advanced readers rely on using the browser's search feature looking for keywords, errors, etc. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`#!/bin/bash` informs the shell to use `bash`, and when you run it with `sh` it does not use `bash` as `sh` is forced.

`sh` is way more limited than `bash`, so if your script uses `bash` logic, but is run via `sh`, it is not fully compatible, and errors out where `sh` does not understand the commands.

Comment: It's useless for me to use  "#!/bin/sh", the result is the same.

Comment: That is exactly what I explained. Your script is written for Bash, you are trying to run it with `sh`, and `sh` does not know what to do with all of the `bash specific` commands..

Comment: The point is, don't use `sh` (or any command) to run your script if you want the shebang to be honored. Make the script executable and use it as the command name. If you insist on passing the script's name as an argument, use `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: I use bash, it doesn't work:  xu@xu-virtual-machine:~$ 
cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
command="paste -d'|' <(echo 22)"
output=`$command`
echo "$output"


xu@xu-virtual-machine:~$ ./test.sh 
paste: '<(echo': No such file or directory